# Unable to get tab url - Chrome extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

After reading through various other posts relating to this problem, I am still unable to find a way to retrieve the current page url. It either returns nothing, "undefined" or "chrome://extensions/".

My code is as follows...

Sample.js

```
var url = [];

chrome.tabs.query({'active': true, 'lastFocusedWindow': true}, function (tabs) {
    url = tabs[0].url;
});

var submitLink = chrome.contextMenus.create(
{
    "title": "Submit " + url
});
```

manifest.json

```
{
  "name": "some name",
  "description": "some description",
  "version": "0.6",
  "permissions": ["tabs","contextMenus"],
  "background": {
    "scripts": ["sample.js"]
  },
  "manifest_version": 2
}
```

Does anyone have any ideas why i cannot get the URL? 
I read somewhere that it was because the chrome.tabs.query function is asynchronous and therefore chrome.contextMenus.create is executed before chrome.tabs.query has retrieved the URL. I have little experience with javascript and so i'm not sure how to get around this.

Your help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: that won't give you current page URL. It will give you the url in the first tab. Your current page could be a different tab. But, yes, what you read is correct. The create call executes before the url is set.

Comment: why not use window.location.href?

Answer (score 0):

try

```
var url = [];
var submitLink;

chrome.tabs.query({'active': true, 'lastFocusedWindow': true}, function (tabs) {
    url = tabs[0].url;
    submitLink = chrome.contextMenus.create({
      "title": "Submit " + url}
    );    
});
```

Comment: Thanks Garr. Although this returns "chrome://extensions/" And window.location.href returns the ID of the extension

Comment: well, the first tab is probably the extensions tab. what are the urls in the other tabs?

Comment: I currently only have a few other tabs open. But it doesn't matter which tabs i have open the result is the same

Answer (score 0):

Your code makes very little sense.

Background page code executes as soon as Chrome starts. Once. Therefore, at best the URL you'll get is the page opened at that time.

Also, context menus are shared by all tabs; it would be strange to put a particular URL there. You'll need to constantly update the menu based on the current tab / URL, like "Submit this page".

Word of advice: **don't do it**. It's really unnecessary complexity at that point. Make a confirmation dialog if needed, but keep the context menu item neutral.

---

But if you absolutely must do it, you need to hook to events from `tabs` API, like changing the active tab with `onActivated` and changing the URL with `onUpdated` / `onReplaced`. It will be complex, but can be done.